# Making input field read only on the value of other input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to make the input field read only on the base of other input field value, for example,

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female <br/>
Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
</form>
```

If someone choose Female, then the age input should become read only, means that it should be fade out then no value can be entered. Is this possible, and how?

Comment: yes, it's possible. Just set the `readonly` property. If it's not working for you, please show your attempted code and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar, i am trying to make readonly Age on the base of Male or female, if someone choose female then it should become readonly otherwise it remains same.

Comment: see [Attribute Equals Selector \[name="value"\]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: I know what you're trying to do, you said that in the question. Please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options on this, but basically if you want a fade effect you need a color to go along with it to display a transition. My answer is an implementation of [jQuery disable enable click event with fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369942/jquery-disable-enable-click-event-with-fade)

**JQuery:**

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "female") {
        // disable input
        $('input[name=age]').fadeOut(20, function () {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            $(this).css('background', '#c0c0c0').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    } else {
        //enable input
        $('input[name=age]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('input[name=age]').css('background', '#ffffff');
    }
});
```

Here is a [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/kshbkoo6/).

**EDIT:**

After playing with this a little bit more I changed the animation lengths to look more natural.

Comment: @dpDesignz, not sure why you didn't get credit for the edit after changing it slightly. But good insight.

Comment: @EternalHour thanks. :). May I ask why you changed the fade values back? I thought you changed the animation for the smooth look. It's still the same on the fiddle?

Comment: @dpDesignz Yeah the fiddle still has the original values, which were the values you used in your edit. I had edited it after that with the new values but did not update the fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using JQuery? try this

```
$('input[type=radio][name=sex]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'female') {
        $("#AgeId").prop("readonly",true);
    }
    else{
        $("#AgeId").prop("readonly",false);
    }
});
```

Comment: you might want to include an `else`, so that when the value is changed the `readonly` is removed.

Comment: I only based it on his statement but putting an else statement is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

In simple way,you can do disable in javascript function.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function female_CLK(){
        document.getElementById("age").readOnly = true;
        document.getElementById("age").style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
    }
</script>

<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" onclick="female_CLK()">Female <br/>
Age: <input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br>
```